# How to make div or span elements really nest

Tags: html, css

I have repeatedly run into this problem and did not find a solution yet.

Example **1**: http://jsfiddle.net/0f5u0w6e/1/

What it Looks like:

[image]

What it should look like:

[image]

In this example the divs should behave like lines, but it is more than that: I want the divs or spans to be **bounding boxes** for all their Contents. (Then it is also impossible that part of their contents pushes parts of another divs content.)

Example **2**: http://jsfiddle.net/gd7Losru/1/

I want the inner (red) span to make the outer (blue) div have a height such that it contains it. (again: bounding box).

*copies of the code if jsFiddle goes offline: Example 1:*

```
<div style="width: 200px;">
    <div>
        Title Title Title 
        <span class="button" 
            style="float: right; padding: 10px;">
            button</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        Config: 
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Example 2:

```
<div style="background-color: blue;">
    <span style="padding: 10px; background-color:red; "></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just clear the float on the second inner div:

```
<div style="width: 200px;">
    <div>
        Title Title Title 
        <span class="button" 
            style="float: right; padding: 10px;">
            button</span>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;">
        Config: 
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0f5u0w6e/2/)

Comment: This also seems like a specialized solution, i want something general to make divs and spans be as large as the bounding box of what they contain.

Comment: And it only makes that "Config" is pushed down too, but still it pushes the Input into another line, it should stay in Config's line. And i dont look for special solutions like nobreak, i need my divs to be bounding boxes

Comment: Seems to be a bug in the webkit engine then. Works in Firefox like a charme in which I tested it. The problem is than that `200px` is not enough space. If I set it to `230px`, it works even in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/0f5u0w6e/5/

Answer (score 0):

You text i.e. 'Config:' is just floating around inside your `div` try puting you text inside a container then you dont need any `float`'s in your css to get what you want

(so you have no floats to clear later and less css to maintain)

```
<div style="width: 200px;">
    <div>
        <label>Title Title Title </label>
        <span class="button" style="padding:10px;">button</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Config: </label>
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
```

Comment: I *need* the button to be on the right. I first tried to do that with `margin-left: auto; margin-right: 0px;` but it didnt do anything.

Comment: it **is** on the right using the code in my answer.

Comment: It should be aligned right-most within the 200px div. And I am looking for a bounding-box solution.

Comment: then you should update your question as you dont mention that requirement

Comment: The question says "bounding box" (now twice).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
input{
    float:right;
}

div{
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/0f5u0w6e/3/

Comment: This only makes that "Config" is pushed down too, but still it pushes the Input into another line, it should stay in Config's line. And i dont look for special solutions like nobreak, i need my divs to be bounding boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a clear:right to the parent div of the input field. Something like this:

```
<div style="clear:right;">
    Config: 
    <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

Avoid inline style and better use classes.

Comment: This seems like a specialized solution, i want something general to make divs and spans be as large as the bounding box of what they contain.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with CSS trick.

```
<div style="width: 220px;">
    <div>
        Title Title Title 
        <span class="button" 
            style="float: right; padding: 10px;">
            button</span>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="aligment">
        <span>Config:</span>
        <span class="input"><input type="text" /></span>
    </div>
</div>

.clear{
    clear: both;
}
.aligment{
    width:100%;
}
.aligment span{
    float:left;
    width: 20%;

}
.aligment span.input{
    float:left;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}
```

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zo3rj14y/)

Comment: Nice trick but i am looking for something more general see my second example.